# inserir dados mutiplos ja havendo dados na db

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Boas, eu estou a ter um problema em adicionar valores na db. Eu quero adicionar um valor num campo que já tem um valor, sem eliminar o valor que lá está, mas sim juntando os dois valores separados por uma virgula. Eu sei que tem qualquer coisa a ver com implode, mas já tentei diversas coisas e não resulta.

Comment: faço um select na db do valor e incluo num implode e introduzo na db certo

Comment: vou tentar obrigado

Comment: Sua coluna no banco é do tipo `varchar`?

Comment: sim, é varchar mas a resposta seguinte resolveu o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que isso resolve:

`UPDATE tabela SET coluna = CONCAT(coluna , ',' , novovalor) WHERE coluna = x`

Comment: Isso **soma** um valor ao outro (caso sejam números), o OP quer **adicionar** mais um valor separado por vírgula.

Comment: Obrigado por avisar @Zulian, editei a resposta.

Comment: resolveu o problema obrigado

Comment: De nada @MusicLyricsHQ. Depois leia esse link: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)